# jQuery: Trying to write my first plugin, how can I pass a selector to my func?

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, css-selectors

I am trying to start writing some simple jQuery plugins and for my first try if figured I would write something that does nothing else but apply `.first` & `.last` classes to passed elements.

so for instance i want to ultimately be able to:

```
$('li').firstnlast();
```

So that in this html structure:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

it would create the following:

```
<ul>
    <li class="first"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="last"></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="first"></li>
    <li class="last"></li>
</ul>
```

What i have written so far in my plugin is this:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.extend({
        firstnlast: function() {
            $(this)
                .first()
                .addClass('first')
                .end()
                .last()
                .addClass('last');
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

However the above only returns this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="first"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li class="last"></li>
</ul>
```

It seems that passing only the `li` into the function it will look at all `li` elements on the entire page and then apply the classes to it.

What I need to figure out is how i can basically make the function 'context aware' so that passing the above `li` into the function would apply the classes to those `li`s inside of the parent `ul`, not to the first and last `li` on the entire page.

Any hints, ideas and help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) and [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) to get those `<li>`s there here, like this:

```
this.filter(':first-child:not(:last-child)').addClass('first')
    .end().filter(':last-child:not(:first-child)').addClass('last');
```

This gets the first and last *with respect to the parent*, which seems to be what you're after, give it a go :)

**Updated:**  Now handles the case of 1 `<li>` inside a `<ul>`, these elements will be ignored.

Comment: Thank you, this works great. However this also applies both classes if there is a `ul` with only 1 `li` element inside. Is there any way I can have this function only apply if there are more than 1 of the given element?

Comment: @Jannis - Try the updated answer, it should ignore these single `<li>` cases.

Comment: Thanks again! This works perfectly and I just learned another cool thing about jQuery. Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.extend({
        firstnlast: function() {
            $(this).parent()
                .find("li:eq(0)")
                .addClass('first')
                .end()
                .find("li:eq(-1)")
                .addClass('last');
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This restricts his extension to working on `<li>` , and if the last `<li>` contained a list with li's...more errors :)

Comment: @Nick Craver...oops, very obvious. Thanks for pointing that out.